# Cyclic ring and visibility problem in pst-solides3d

Tags: pstricks, 3d

I'm trying to draw two cylindric rings on top of each other with `pst-solides3d`. Here is what I have:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\begin{document}

    \begin{pspicture}(0,0)(3,5)

    \psset{viewpoint=60 80 30 rtp2xyz,Decran=60,lightsrc=viewpoint}

    \psSolid[object=anneau, h=1.7, R=4.4, r=3.8](0,0, 0.77)

    \psSolid[object=anneau, h=0.6, R=5, r=4.4](0,0,0.46)

    \end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

And here is what if gives (`latex doc.tex; dvips doc.dvi; ps2pdf doc.ps`):

[image]

And a view from the bottom (change `30` to `-50` in `psset`):

[image]

Have I done a silly mistake or there is a visibility problem ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you draw the rings without using hidden surfaces. In this case the second polygon surfaces are simply drawn over the first ones. You have to collect *all* polygon surfaces and then draw them by using `object=fusion`, then hidden surfaces are taken into account.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,5)
 \psset{viewpoint=60 80 30 rtp2xyz,Decran=60,lightsrc=viewpoint,solidmemory}
 \psSolid[object=anneau,h=1.7,R=4.4,r=3.8,
          name=A1,action=none,hue=0 1](0,0, 0.77)% no action, name=A1
 \psSolid[object=anneau,h=0.6,R=5,r=4.4,
          name=A2,action=none](0,0,0.46)%          no action, name=A2
 \psSolid[object=fusion,base=A1 A2]
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]